# ¿Para que sirve heredar de Object en Python?

Tags: python, poo, objeto, herencia

Me ha surgido una duda revisando código de otras personas al aprender a usar clases y objetos en Python, y es que, ¿Qué utilidad tiene heredar de object al crear una clase? Por ejemplo:

```
class Persona(object):
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad

    def saludar(self):
        print(f"Hola me llamo {self.nombre} y tengo {self.edad} años")


p1 = Persona("Gian", 16)
p1.saludar()
```

¿Cambia algo al heredar de object?
¿O es exactamente lo mismo que no hacerlo?

Comment: Para *nada*, mentira, no es necesario heredar de `Object` ya que por defecto toda clase que crees ya hereda de este. Podrías pensar en `Object` como el tipo de dato primitivo de las clases. Por lo que Sí, es lo mismo que no hacerlo.

Comment: Ah entonces genial, gracias @Christian

Comment: Si hay una diferencia. El código que tienes puede que sea de python 2.1 o anterior. https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes.html

Comment: @loki La evidencia de que usa _f-strings_ indica que es python3.6 mínimo. No funcionaría con python2 de todos modos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estás aprendiendo hoy día Python asumo que muy probablemente estás aprendiendo directamente Python 3. Todas las clases en Python 3 son de "nuevo estilo", por lo que todas heredan de `object`, por lo que es opcional ponerlo o no. No hace absolutamente ninguna diferencia. Si no lo pones va a heredar de `object` igualmente.

Los lugares donde lo ves puesto explícitamente es porque escogen ponerla por ejemplo para que sea compatible con Python 2, dado que es habitual que hoy día sigan utilizándose programas de Python 2 o que se sigan usando intérpretes de Python 2 (los cuales corren gran parte del código el cual es común con Python 3). Aunque es poco habitual que se desarrollen programas específicos para Python 2 sí que hay gran cantidad de documentación escrita en la época que Python 2 era la principal versión utilizada (ya que estuvo mantenida desde el año 2000 hasta el 2020).

Adicionalmente te comento en líneas generales, puesto que hoy día es irrelevante, que hasta Python 2.1 incluído solo existían las clases de "estilo antiguo" (que no heredaban de `object`), pero a partir de Python 2.2 estuvieron conviviendo las clases de "estilo nuevo" y de "estilo antiguo". Entonces era necesario explicitar que las de nuevo estilo sí heredan de object, ahora que las de "estilo antiguo" ya no existen en Python 3, se ha convertido en innecesario.

Answer (score 4):

Primero hay que recordar que en Python todo es un objeto, todo dato en Python es representado por objetos.

#### object

Todo dato deriva de `Object`, esta es una clase base de cualquier dato en Python y puede ser comprobado con la funcion `isinstance()`

```
print(isintance(int,object))
#salida-> True

print(isintance("uan cadena",object))
#salida-> True
```

Todas las clases son subclases de `object` por lo que cualquier objeto es una instancia de object. Al crear una nueva clase por defecto ya se hereda de la clase `object` pues esta es la principal y la base de todo. Esta clase contiene *el esqueleto* o las *funcionalidades* necesarias para poder crear otras clases como por ejemplo `__getattribute__` o los *dunder methods* a veces llamados *métodos magicos*.

Recuerda que al crear una clase creas un nuevo tipo de dato y por eso todo lo que ves en Python es un objeto, demostrado con el anterior ejemplo. Luego tambien existe la metaclase `type()`, spoiler -> no hereda de `object`, pero eso esta fuera del tema de la pregunta.

Creo que ya te habrás dado cuenta que no es necesario heredar de `object` y que esto no supone ninguna diferencia en tu código, igual puedes sobrescribir algunos métodos si consideras necesario.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info!

Comment: @GianLópez para mi opinión esta pregunta debería ser la marcada como resuelta, amigo :-)